# Изменил файлы в Laravel Vendor как вернуть все обратно?

Tags: laravel, composer

Изменил файлы в vendor папке, как вернуть все обратно, есть ли команда для новой генерации vendor файлов или придется все удалить и снова `composer install` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас сохранился прежним composer.lock и вы удалите все пакеты, а после  запустите `composer install`, то пакеты установятся точно тех же версий, что и прежде - информация для установки будет взята из composer.lock файла.

Но можно обойтись без удаления всех пакетов. Достаточно узнать - файлы из каких пакетов были изменены: `composer status -v`, удалить пакеты с измененными файлами, а после - запустить `composer install`.